# Waiting for multiple HTML changes before action

Tags: jquery, html, loading

Ok so basically, I have an ajax call that makes changes to the database and gets new pictures to display. I am now trying not to show the pictures until their loading is done.

```
$('.leftPicture').hide(0);
$('.rightPicture').hide(0);

varData = [...];
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
    url: "ajax/save.php",
    data: varData,
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    success: function(result) {
        $('.leftPicture').attr('id', result[0]);
        $('.leftPicture img').attr('src', "[...]");
        $('.rightPicture').attr('id', result[1]);
        $('.rightPicture img').attr('src', "[...]");

        $('.leftPicture').show(0);
        $('.rightPicture').show(0);
    }
});
```

Unfortunately, sometimes (depending on the browser), the old picture is shown again right before the new one is. How can I fix this and still make it look "snappy" ? I don't believe using a `delay()` or a `setTimeout()` would be the best choice since the picture might take less time to load.

Comment: It's simple, just use `.load()`

Answer (score 1):

Try using `.load()` like this-

```
success: function(result) {
        $('.leftPicture img').attr('src', "[...]").load(function(){
           $('.leftPicture').show(0); // wait until image is loaded
        })
    }
```

Comment: This seems to work but it sometimes gets stuck in the `display: none;` style (that is induced by the `hide()`). What could be the cause ?